# validate POST data from swagger json.schema in node

Tags: json, node.js, api, swagger, jsonschema

In a swagger spec, I define the schema of the object that is returned by a query.  That's great for GETs but if I have a POST endpoint, it could have that same object in it. Can I specify a `json.schema` for the "parameters" that are POSTed to an endpoint?  That is do a `$ref: #/definitions/myObject`? It would suck to have to define the schema twice, once for incoming and once for outgoing.

And then is it possible to have middleware validate the payload of a post against that `json.schema` and reject if the payload does not comply?

It seems that all the pieces are available, so now I'm wondering if it's been pulled together or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems I can't discover anything before posting in desperation.  But I found it.

In the docs, surprisingly. [Paramnerters](http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterIn).  If you declare a parameter type of "body" then you can/must declare a schema type. As in json.schema.  So that's part one.

Then for part two there is middleware for node in [swagger-tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/blob/master/docs/Middleware.md#swagger-validator) that validates the request and optionally the response.  While it's not exactly explicit I believe that it will validate the body against the schema, so that's pretty cool.  I don't know what kind of error messages it generates, hopefully something either configurable or at least intelligible.